# Selectize.js how does getAdjacentOption() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I've been using selectize.js, but I'm a bit stuck at the usage of `getAdjacentValue()`.

In the API one finds:

> getAdjacentOption(value, direction)` Retrieves the jQuery element for the previous or next option, relative to the currently highlighted option. The "direction" argument should be 1 for "next" or -1 for "previous".

Minimal working example, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dietervdf/bcgc4f0v/2/).

```
<select id='car' name='car'>
  <option value='1'>Mercedes</option>
  <option value='2' selected>BMW</option>
  <option value='3'>Volvo</option>
</select>
```

And .js

```
$('select').selectize();
var obj = $('select')[0].selectize;
```

But how can I get the next and prev value of the current selected item?
I don't get how to implement the API help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation is not very clear about what the `value` argument is suppose to be when calling `getAdjacentOption(value, direction)`.

If you lookup `getAdjacentOption` in the source of selectize.js you will find

```
getAdjacentOption: function($option, direction) {
    var $options = this.$dropdown.find('[data-selectable]');
    var index    = $options.index($option) + direction;

    return index >= 0 && index < $options.length ? $options.eq(index) : $();
},
```

This is telling us that `getAdjacentOption` makes use of the jQuery `.index()` method, which accepts a selector or an element.

So calling `obj.getAdjacentOption(2,1)` can not give you the expected result, because you are passing in an int to the function as the first argument.

But calling it like so `obj.getAdjacentOption("2",1)` will not help either, even if `"2"` might be the value of your current selected option.

To make a long story short pass in the current selected element.

Here is an example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $select = $('select').selectize();
  var obj = $select[0].selectize;
  obj.refreshOptions(false);
  
  var crnt = obj.getOption(obj.getValue());

  console.log("Prev option is:",
              obj.getAdjacentOption(crnt,-1).text(),
              "with a value of",
              obj.getAdjacentOption(crnt,-1).data("value"));  
  
  console.log("Next option is:",
              obj.getAdjacentOption(crnt,1).text(),
              "with a value of",
              obj.getAdjacentOption(crnt,1).data("value"));

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.2/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.2/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

<select id='car' name='car'>
  <option value='1'>Mercedes</option>
  <option value='2' selected>BMW</option>
  <option value='3'>Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great answer, the 'refreshOptions(false)' seems mandatory (it doesn't work without it), any idea why?

Comment: oh, and I would like to know what 'crnt' stands for :)

Comment: `crnt`  is just an abbreviation for "current", but `curr` or just `cur` would probably be a better choice :).  `refreshOptions(false)` is actually necessary for some of the API Options methods to return useful values. At least when you are adding them as HTML elements. Guess there is some re-initialization taking place.

Answer (score 0):

To improve what DavidDomain said, I have a button to go to the next value in the select, so I did this:

```
$('#btnNext').click(function(){
    var $select = $('#ddlClients').selectize();
    var obj = $select[0].selectize;
    obj.refreshOptions(false);

    var crnt = obj.getOption(obj.getValue());
    var next = obj.getAdjacentOption(crnt, 1).data("value");
    obj.setValue(next); //here is where the value is setted as selected
});
```

This way, when I click the button "Next", the next item in the dropdown is set as selected.